# Passing selected rows between ViewControllers and conditional segues in Swift

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

I'm working on my first app and I've got the UI sketched out, but before I move forward, I've hit a stumbling block out of the gate that's not in the tutorials I've been studying.

```
Two issues I have:
1) Passing data between TableViewControllers
2) Conditional Segues
```

The app uses CoreData and has a context with 3 managed objects in the model: `FocusArea`, `Equipment`, & `Activity`.

A portion of my app will have 3 TableViews that display fetched results from `FocusArea`, `Equipment`, & `Activity`. The navigation through them will be as follows:

```
Step 1          -> Step 2       -> Step 3       -> save selections
focusAreaTVC    -> equipmentTVC -> activityTVC  -> saveVC
equipmentTVC    -> focusAreaTVC -> activityTVC  -> saveVC
activityTVC     -> focusAreaTVC -> equipmentTVC -> saveVC
```

When an item/items is/are selected in Step 1, a "next" button will advance to Step 2, display options available for rows selected in Step 1. Once the user makes selections in Step 2, the remaining available selections will be displayed in Step 3. I envision the final selections on the Save screen to be saved as an array or a dictionary.

Issues:
1) View Controllers: Rather than use 9 different ViewControllers, I plan to use `performSegueWithIdentifier` so I only need to set up 3 view controllers for the objects and figure out the logic to accomplish the transitions.

Would I create a global variable in `AppDelegate` for the TVC at each step and put logic in a switch statement for each VC within `performSequeWithIdentifier`?

example:

```
// AppDelegate variables start all nil, updated at each step, reset to nil on save
var step1VC = "equipmentVCUsed"
var step2VC = "focusAreaTVCUsed"
var step3VC = nil

// VC switch statement (contained in each TableViewController)
var segueIdentifier: String

switch segueName {
case step1TVC = "focusAreaTVC":
    segueName = "equipmentTVC"
case step1TVC = "equipmentTVC:
    segueName = "focusAreaTVC"
case step1TVC = "activityTVC":
    segueName = "focusAreaTVC"
case step2TVC = "equipmentTVC":
    segueName = "activityTVC"
case step2TVC = "focusAreaTVC", step1VC = "equipmentVC":
    segueName = "activityTVC"
case step2TVC = "focusAreaTVC", step1VC = "activityVC":
    segueName = "equipmentTVC"
case step3VC != nil,
    segueName = "saveVC"
    step1TVC = nil
    step2TVC = nil
default:
    println("Something so the the compiler doesn't yell at me")
}
```

2) I plan to make selections in Step 1 and pass them to Step 2's VC, further refine there, pass to Step 3. Since they're all working off the same context, can I just pass the selections from 1 TVC to another or do I need to create a list that the next VC will retrieve items from?

How would I get the information from Step 1 to Step 3? Would I have to save the selections in an Array between segues and refine them with fetches in each VC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just let the segues be triggered by taps on a table view cell? In other words, make it like this: User selects option from first table view -> User then sees second table view and selects from the appropriate set of options -> User then sees third table view and selects from the appropriate set of options.  You can always put a back button at the top so the user can go back and change his/her selections.

Your users might want, and expect, your app to behave like this.

Anyway, to answer your questions:

1) I suggest that you create a UIViewController superclass from which your subclasses inherit, then define a property in that class's .h file that can be set to an object that contains whatever data each view controller needs to pass to the next view controller. Then, use prepareForSegue to pass along the data that the next view controller will need to have.

2) You can pass the selections from 1 TVC to another (see #1)

Edit:  If you need any clarification, or if you feel I am misunderstanding your question, please feel free to leave a comment.  I got less than 5 hours of sleep last night.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to keep it all in Swift and I'd like to avoid messing w/ Objective C. I started learning Obj-C/CoreData and Apple switched to Swift when I was ~1/2 way done. I understand the basics of it, but I'd rather not monkey with Obj-C if I don't have to.

I'm not adding anything to the SQLite DB. I'm just selecting, refining, and saving a list.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I thought it over at the gym and I think you're right...needlessly complicated. I think I'm going to make a selector VC that sets parameters to plug into the TVC to display. #LessDrama